# Algoritmos/Ciclos - Reescribir algoritmo utilizando ciclos ciclos 1-n

Tags: algoritmos

Estoy haciendo ejercicios de algoritmos I y tengo una duda sobre el enunciado que solicita hacer ciclos 1-n.

El enunciado es: Reescribir los algoritmos MI-16 al MI-18, utilizando ciclos 1-n

Y los MI-16 al MI-18 son los siguientes:

**MI-16:** Ingresar e informar valores, mientras que el valor ingresado no sea negativo. Informar la cantidad de valores ingresados.

**MI-18:** Dado un valor M determinar y emitir un listado con los M primeros múltiplos de 3 que no lo sean de 5, dentro del conjunto de los números naturales

¿Qué sería un ciclo 1-n?

Comment: Entiendo que simplemente dice que el algoritmo va a ejecutar un número de iteraciones de 1 a n. En el primer caso si el primer nº es negativo se ejecuta un único ciclo pero pueden ser n (indeterminados). En el segundo caso depende del valor de M que puede ir de 1 a n (indeterminado):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente se trata de un ciclo que se ejecute la primera vez y que dependiendo de lo que pase dentro de el, se puede ejecutar n numero de veces hasta que suceda algo que lo termine.

## EJEMPLO

Se mostrara una ventana una vez y si ingresan una letra la imprimirá en pantalla, luego vuelve a mostrar la ventana y si ingresan otra letra la imprimirá también, luego vuelve a salir la ventana y si ingresan un numero fallara y saldrá del ciclo, si nunca ingresan un numero se ejecutara n numero de veces que se ingrese bien el dato. pero se cumplió con que se ejecutara la primera vez.